# PHP/Wordpress: Echo <div> containing all attached images of a post?

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, wordpress

For a Wordpress theme, I would like to create a function (to include in the content.php) that gets all images attached to a post, creates an `<img>`-string for each image and finally creates and echoes a `<div>` containing all these `<img>`-strings.

So far I am able to get all the images and create the `<img>`-strings, but I struggle with putting them in a new `<div>`. My so far functioning code looks like this:

```
function create_imageslideshow() {

    // Get the post ID
    $iPostID = $post->ID;

    // Get images for this post
    $arrImages = get_attached_media( 'image' . $iPostID  );

    // If images exist for this post
    if($arrImages) {

        // Get array keys representing attached image numbers
        $arrKeys = array_keys($arrImages);

        foreach ($arrKeys as $iNum) {

          // Get the full sized image url for the attachment
          $sImageUrl = wp_get_attachment_url($iNum);

          // Build the <img> string (parse regular <img>-tag)
          $sImgString = 

            '<img id="' . $iNum . '"" src="' . $sImageUrl . '"  alt="Thumbnail Image" title="Thumbnail Image" />';

          // Print the image
          echo $sImgString;
        }

        // Build slideshow ???

    }
}
```

This successfully creates an `<img>`-tag for each image and echoes it so the images show up on the website. But rather than just echoing the images, I need them echoed inside a `<div>`. Is there a way to put all the strings created for each image in an array which I can then put inside a new string for the `<div>`?

Comment: Every image tag with new div or all images in one single div?

Comment: @Khushboo all images in one div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Sorry, posting from phone.

```
function create_imageslideshow() {

// Get the post ID
$iPostID = $post->ID;

// Get images for this post
$arrImages = get_attached_media( 'image' . $iPostID  );

// If images exist for this post
if($arrImages) {

    echo "<div class='test'>";

    // Get array keys representing attached image numbers
    $arrKeys = array_keys($arrImages);

    foreach ($arrKeys as $iNum) {

      // Get the full sized image url for the attachment
      $sImageUrl = wp_get_attachment_url($iNum);

      // Build the <img> string (parse regular <img>-tag)
      $sImgString = 

        '<img id="' . $iNum . '"" src="' . $sImageUrl . '"  alt="Thumbnail Image" title="Thumbnail Image" />';

      // Print the image
      echo $sImgString;
    }

    echo "</div>";

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, can't test it now but will do so later. Is it really that simple? Just wrapping the foreach loop in a couple of echoes printing the <div>-tag?

Comment: Yes, you can test it whenever you get time 

Comment: Perfect, your solution does exactly what I need, thanks!